# Is there such thing as a ".tiff editor?"

Tags: mac, text-editors, tiff

What I'm looking for it something that automatically translates the hex in tiff files into the corresponding categories and values that are found in a tiff file, and hopefully be able to add/remove text rather easily. Does such a thing exist?

**Edit:** On a mac

Comment: Just a clarification. Despite the title it sounds like what you are really looking for is a tool to extract the TIFF TAGS to a new file. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a parser rather than an editor you want,
[**Hachoir parser**](http://freshmeat.net/projects/hachoir-parser) might work -- though I have never tried it myself.

In general, I think there should be modules in Perl, Python, etc to parse TIFF files.
Therefore, there should be tools to dump headers for TIFF.
`Hachoir parser` is a Python tool.

Answer (score 1):

Are you after ImageMagiks [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php)?

Answer (score 0):

TIFF files are images, so there's no much text in them. Most of the image processing programs will be able to handle them (Photoshop for example).

Since you mention text, I'm guessing that you have faxes saved as TIFF files, so text in them is not really text--you'll need OCR software which will scan TIFF file into text document which you can then edit.

Unfortunately I can't recommend free image editing or OCR software on Mac since I'm not a Mac user, but perhaps someone can chime in.

Comment: actually, no - i was wondering if software existed where for example the tiff header would be translated into english, etc. So instead of just seeing hex, I would see the file broken up into the header, IFDs, etc. Basically, I need to convert a custom image file format into a tif file and it seems intimidating to have to literally write python scripts that write hex to a file instead of english, which is what i am used to.

Comment: The headers are not in Hex. All data is stored in binary representation regardless of the file type. It sounds like whatever you are viewing those headers with is displaying hex, which is a common representation of the Tag header numbers and offsets. Are you sure you are looking at the actual tag data instead of the tag identifiers?